# UIWebView inside UIScrollView: scroll working but view not resizing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I am new in iOS programming and I am trying to have a view in storyboard with a `UIImageView` on top and a uiWebView below it. I set a `UIScrollView` that contains both of them and I would like that the scroll make the image disappearing while going down.

I follow this answer ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440448/ios-uiwebview-inside-a-uiscrollview)) and I got the scroll working but the `UIWebView` does not resize itself properly. I have tried many solutions around, but if I get the web view resizing I do not get scroll working anymore and vice versa.

Particularly, I am using:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    _textDetailNews.delegate = self; // the web view delegate
    _textDetailNews.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    [_textDetailNews loadHTMLString:description baseURL:nil]; // set text to be shown in web view
}
```

and

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview 
{
   CGFloat height = [[_textDetailNews stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight"] floatValue];

   [_scrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width, height + _scrollView.frame.size.height)];

   CGRect oldBounds = [[self textDetailNews] frame];
   [_textDetailNews setFrame:CGRectMake(oldBounds.origin.x, oldBounds.origin.y, oldBounds.size.width, height)];
}
```

Where `_scrollView` already contains the `UIImageView` and the `UIWebView` set from storyboard.

Please, I appreciate any help for make the scrolling and `UIWebView` height resizing working.

**EDIT**

I am trying to make it more clear. The `UIScrollView` works fine with the above code but the `UIWebView` does not change its frame. While if I do not call: `setContentSize` on `_srollView` the `UIWebView` change size but the view does not scroll anymore.

Can somebody told me where is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You must delegate the "UIScrollViewDelegate" protocol. And in .m file you must implement the methods:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(CGFloat)scale
```

for example:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return nil;
    return scrollView.subviews.firstObject;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(CGFloat)scale
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks for you replay, I've tried but it is not working. My view is still scrolling buy the web view is not resigning. So, scrolling down result into an empty view. Do you have other hints?

Comment: are you sure the UIScrollView is on the top?

Comment: Perhaps it behinds some sibling views.
You can use setZoomScale method to resize scrollView

- (void)setZoomScale:(CGFloat)scale animated:(BOOL)animated

Answer (score 0):

Since you are telling that you tried many permutations. So i am giving you one approach **not an actual answer**

I have worked that kind of application, And i was facing issue like you said, So i have used `UITableView` instead of `UIScrollView` and add `UIWebView` as a separate `UITableViewCell`.

Hope this will help a bit.

Comment: thanks, it seems to be a good option. Anyway, I am wandering if the problem would remain since apple documentation suggest that the problem of double scrolling objects occurs within UIWebView inside an UIScrollView or UITableView.

Comment: You have to choose option between two that either you have to scroll UIWebView or its container view. So that at a time only one view will scroll.

Answer (score 0):

If you are embedding an UIWebView in an UIScrollView then perhaps you are running into the warning posted in the Class Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html

> IMPORTANT
>   You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.

If you only need to include an image on-top of the UIWebView, is it possible to embed the image into the HTML?

Similar to: [Using HTML and Local Images Within UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747407/using-html-and-local-images-within-uiwebview)

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with this problem from a very long time.
I also used the same link you used,Put a UIview and webview inside scrollview,still it was not working properly.webview's contentsize was wrong.
**I solved it by putting the webview inside another uiview** then inside uiscroll view,not directly inside scrollview.
hope that helps.