# UIWebView and UITableView scroll at the same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have a `UIWebView` in my `UITableView` cell. However when I scroll the `UIWebView`, `UITableView` scrolls too. How do I make sure only one `UIWebView` scrolls when the user tries to scroll it?

Comment: Nothing fancy, I just do webview.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
        parent.addSubview(webview) on cell's main view.

Comment: see this once it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440448/ios-uiwebview-inside-a-uiscrollview

Answer (score 2):

> This Question has not been answered yet so i am posting my answer so
>   late .

I had the same problem , i solved with creating custom Delegate. follow the steps below.

**1.** Create Custom delegate in your `UITableViewCell`

```
@protocol MyTableCellDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)webViewDidStartedScrolling;
-(void)webViewDidStoppedScrolling;

@end
```

**2.** Add `UIScrollViewDelegate` in your `TableCell.h` file

```
@interface TableCell : UITableViewCell<UIWebViewDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate>
property(weak,nonatomic) id<MyTableCellDelegate> delegateWebView;
```

**3.** in your `TableCell.m` file

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.myWebView.scrollView.delegate=self;
   }

 //ScrollView delegate method 
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
      if(self.delegateWebView && [self.delegateWebView respondsToSelector:@selector(webViewDidStoppedScrolling)]){
         [self.delegateWebView webViewDidStoppedScrolling];
     }
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

    if(self.delegateWebView && [self.delegateWebView respondsToSelector:@selector(webViewDidStartedScrolling)]){
        [self.delegateWebView webViewDidStartedScrolling];

    }
 }
```

**4.**  add `MyTableCellDelegate` in your `UIViewController.h` where you are having Your table View.

```
   @interface UIViewController ()<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,MyTableCellDelegate>
```

**5.** Implement the methods of your custom delegate methods  in your `UIViewController.m` file , and **enable**  or **disable** `tableView` scrolling , when your `webviewDidEndScrolling` and `webviewDidStartedScrolling`

```
#pragma mark UItableView Delegate

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 YourTableCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YourTableCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.delegateDealDetails=self;

}
// Custom Delegate Callback method
-(void)webViewDidStartedScrolling
{
    tblDealDetails.scrollEnabled=NO;
}

-(void)webViewDidStoppedScrolling
{

    tblDealDetails.scrollEnabled=YES;
}
```

This works fine for me , i hope this will help others who is facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an disable and enable scroll of the tableView, when the webView scroll delegate is called.
UIWebView has a scrollView inside, that you can be I'ts delegate.

```
- (void)setupSwip
{
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer*   swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwip:)];
    swipeGesture.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];

    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    return YES;
}

- (void)didSwip:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{

}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{   
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if (!decelerate)
    {
        self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: With this I can't scroll the main tableview at all at the start.